# Authenticate users using their firstname

Tags: postfix, dovecot, openldap

I'm setting up a Postfic and Dovecot with LDAP email server. My users in LDAP is like this:

```
dn: uid=firstname,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
uid: firstname
uidNumber: 4025
gidNumber: 4025
givenName: firstname
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/firstname
cn: firstname lastname
mail: firstname.lastname@domain.com
```

This is how I connect Dovecot with LDAP

```
hosts = ldapserver
ldap_version = 3
base = ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
deref = never
scope = subtree
user_attrs =
user_filter = (&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=%n)
pass_attrs = uid=user,userPassword=password
pass_filter = (&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=%n))
default_pass_scheme = SSHA
```

When I enter a user's email address and password as the following:
email: firstname.lastname@domain.com

password: password

and according to my setting which I used "%n" as you see above, the username used to authenticate is "firstname.lastname". I checked the Dovecot variables but I couldn't find something useful in this case to manipulate the "%n" variable.

I would like to keep using email addresses as "firstname.lastname@domain.com" but authenticate users using their first name. I really hit a wall here and any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't already have the email address in your LDAP data, I would recommend to add it.

Search for the full email address

```
user_filter = (&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Please see my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use the full email address as the username. Here is my settings:

```
hosts = LDAP server address
dn = cn=manager,dc=domain,dc=com
dnpass = password
ldap_version = 3
base = ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
deref = never
scope = subtree
user_attrs =
user_filter = (&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u)
pass_attrs = mail=user,userPassword=password
pass_filter = (&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(mail=%u))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate as the firstname.lastname and later on see the full email address (as if that would have been used for authentication) you need to set the userdb_user:

```
pass_attrs = userdb_user=mail
```